# Intent para abrir ficha película en app Movistar+ Android

Tags: android

¿Existe alguna manera de lanzar un `intent` para abrir la app de Movistar con una pantalla detalle de una película/serie? Todo apunta a que es una web-app sin `Activity` con algún `<intent-filter>` que lo permita.

Sería lo mismo que se puede hacer con Netflix, para el cual se puede enviar un `intent` con su `package` `com.netflix.mediaclient` apuntando a `com.netflix.mediaclient.ui.launch.UIWebViewActivity` añadiendo como extra al `intent` la Uri de la película (`http://www.netflix.com/watch/ + videoId`) y voilà, la app de Netflix abre el contenido solicitado.

Comment: Depende de si la app de Movistar soporta deep link. Yo no he sido capaz de encontrar información al respecto, así que probablemente no o, al menos, no está documentado

Comment: Exacto, me preguntaba si alguien haciendo pruebas a lo loco había dado con algún deeplink válido, porque como dices no existe ninguna info al respecto en ninguna parte. Gracias

Comment: ¿Y a través de una API, si la tienen?

Comment: De la app no hay documentada ninguna API para poder comunicarse con ella... Analizando el manifiesto del apk de su app os confirmo de que no tienen ninguna Activity que soporte deep-linking.